# atom editor. in alert ("hello") there is an error [validatequotemarks]

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I use atom editor. In `alert ("hello")` there is an error:

> [validatequotemarks] invalid quote mark found.

In JavaScript also same error is also reported.

It works in notepad but not in atom editor?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>    
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("hello");
 document.write("my name is");
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste that code here, or type it in? A common cause for an error like "invalid quotes" in code is using typographical or "curly" quote marks, e.g. `“hello”` instead of `"hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to single quotes:

```
alert('hello');
```

and see if the error goes away. Both double quotes and single quotes are valid in JavaScript, but some linting tools allow one to be specified, and it could be that your settings in Atom are set to require single quotes.

Comment: thanks.but i don't know how to do. can you explain shortly?